# Jsf inputFile file size

Tags: jsf, file-upload, jsf-2

I have this input file field in my form to upload file.

```
    <h:form id="stammdaten" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<h:inputFile id="profileImage" value="#{stammdatenController.file}" />
</h:form>
```

Above code upload file properly. But the problem is if I select file bigger than 1Mb then it does not get uploaded. Only files less than 1Mb gets uploaded properly.

How can I increase this file upload limit to 2Mb?

**Edit:**
my web.xml

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
    </session-config>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>primefaces.CLIENT_SIDE_VALIDATION</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_REFRESH_PERIOD</param-name>
        <param-value>0</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>facelets.SKIP_COMMENTS</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

and my backing bean:

```
private Part file;

    public void upload() throws IOException{
        try (InputStream input = file.getInputStream()) {
            FileUtils.copyToFile(input, new File("/home/john/Pictures/uploads/test.jpg"));
        }
}
```

Comment: Zero info about used JSF (`h:inputFile` has (had?) so many problems in Mojarra), zero info about used server (and those problems are almost always server/config related), zero info about error message (you select a file and absolutely nothing happens?). Do you have `multipart-config` in `web.xml`?

Comment: I have updated my question with more info. Just a note, I didn't do any server/config for file upload. And, if I submit the form, there is no error on server log, I am redirected to the same page after form submission

Comment: Server info is important as all servers have a post size limitation which needs to be configured via server specific settings. 1MB is however quite low (assuming you meant MB instead of Mb, of course).

Comment: I am using spring boot built in tomcat server. So I added `spring.http.multipart.max-file-size=10Mb # Max file size.`
`spring.http.multipart.max-request-size=10Mb # Max request size.` and in web.xml I also added same size according to the answer below. I also tried primefaces and faced same 1MB problem

Comment: I have complete project on github  https://github.com/shiblybcc/javaoutgoingerasmus/tree/3-way-join-table

Answer (score 0):

Update your `web.xml`:

```
 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    <multipart-config>
        <max-file-size>put_your_desired_value</max-file-size>
        <max-request-size>also_here_request_size</max-request-size>
        <file-size-threshold>and_here_in_bytes</file-size-threshold>
    </multipart-config>
</servlet>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is not working. I think I am missing something simple here. After I submit the form, page just refresh. It doesn't actually send the form to the server.